# Route taken by a query/url

Tags: url, server, routes

I want to know the route(all the intermediate servers/routers/etc. and final destination) taken by a query/url to fetch data fetched from a server.

For example: `http://coreapi.imagin8ors.org:8080/v1/child/140df552-eba9-42c3-8c9e-6d478637925f/learningpods_new/`

Any Online tools or software's to do the same?

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `traceroute` to trace down all the nodes in the path while querying a domain name.

But, please note that the command may fail for URLs containing parameters like the one you have provided in your question. The command takes only the domain name as argument, not complete URL with extra parameters. Example:

```
traceroute coreapi.imagin8ors.org
```

and not:

```
traceroute http://coreapi.imagin8ors.org:8080/v1/child/140df552-eba9-42c3-8c9e-6d478637925f/learningpods_new/
```

The point to understand here is that the domain name is mapped to a specific source of a resource and the extra parameters after the domain name in a URL is to specify a particular resource from that source. Hence no matter what the full URL is, only the domain name matters for the path to be taken by the packets.

So, given any URL you could safely extract out the domain name and trace the path using `traceroute` command with the URL to get the path you are looking for.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: The "traceroute" command is different for different OS, for windows it's "tracert", for Mac, it's different, etc. Thank you.